# How to fetch date in iOS from string object

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have stored NSDate in the DB using http://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/.

When i fetch the date back to NSString i get following during debugging. (As mentioned in tutorial even though i have a date picker and store value in NSDate, its actually stored as string in DB finally.

```
 (lldb) po _itemPurchaseDate
```

(
  )

Attached screenshot. So how do i fetch date and present it in a ui label in iOS?

[image]

Comment: Please convert NSDate to NSData and then save it to db and later retrieve NSData and convert it to the date.

Comment: Did you ever log what's inside the label? if you don't want to use nsdata, you might be able to use nsdateformatter to convert the string back to nsdate.